# Unable to close iframe reference in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I've created a reference of iframe, which I sends to an API call as a parameter. After I get a response I want to close that iframe but when I use "iframe.close" it doesn't closes.

```
    let refIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    refIframe.setAttribute('id', 'refIframe');
    refIframe.setAttribute('src', 'www.google.com');
    refIframe.style.zIndex = '2';
    refIframe.style.display = 'block';
    refIframe.style.width = '30%';
    refIframe.style.height = '92vh';
    refIframe.style.margin = '2% 35%';
    document.body.after(refIframe, document.body);
    let iframe = document.getElementById('refIframe').contentWindow;
    checkout.params.windowRef = document.getElementById('refIframe').contentWindow;
```

Once the response is received from the API calls I do the following to close the reference of the iframe.

```
    iframe.close();
```

but by doing this my iframe doesn't close.

Can anyone please guide me what am I doing wrong thereby my iframe doesn't close.
If modified code is provided it'll be really helpful for me to understand.

Please it'll be really helpful if some can tell me to create iframe reference without using componentDidMount.

Comment: is your goal to remove the iframe from the dom?

Comment: Yes my goal is to remove the iframe from DOM OR if without removing it from DOM can the iframe be closed once the response is received from the API called in the iframe.

Comment: `OR if without removing it from DOM can the iframe be closed once the response is received from the API called in the iframe.` I am not sure you mean by "closed." I posted an answer that removes it from the DOM, which in my opinion is effectively closing it.

Comment: Ok I edited the answer to also include another interpretation of the word "close"

Comment: Hi did `.remove()` solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated that your goal is to remove the iframe from the dom. Try the following instead of `iframe.close()`:

```js
setTimeout(()=>{

  document.getElementById('refIframe').remove()

}, 2000)
//placed inside a timeout for demonstration purposes only... so you can see the iframe being removed from dom
```

```html
<div>Element Before Iframe</div>
<iframe id="refIframe"></iframe>
<div>Element After Iframe</div>
```

If however you want to keep the `<iframe>` element but you want the page inside the iframe to stop being "open", you could modify the iframe's `src` attribute to be something else (even an empty string), thus "navigating" away from the current page within the iframe.

```js
setTimeout(()=>{

  document.getElementById('refIframe').src = "" 
  //setting to empty string will put no webapge inside the iframe

},2000)
```

```html
<iframe id="refIframe" src="https://wikipedia.org"></iframe>
```